# Flowchart control for ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, svg

I need to build a flowchart control for Asp.net with html/jquery/silverlight/Scalable Vector Graphics(SVG). The user need to design the flowchart in the web page and need to save it. Please suggest some good implementation.I tried some API's like [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/developer/apidocs/rest/) and [Grapholite](http://grapholite.com/) but not suitable for my scenario as this API need live internet connection. Now I'm trying with jsplump.

Please help me out, Also please share any free controls for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and save flowcharts in [mxgraph.com](http://www.mxgraph.com). It's not a control, but the output is XML, .NET can parse that easily.

Comment: Yes i saw that,but i need work it offline. Need embed in my web page.